# Erlang - how to convert \u0000 character to binary?

Tags: unicode, erlang

I have a problem with converting unicode character to binary.

Code:

```
Text = "\u0000partner\u0000"
Bin = term_to_binary(Text, [compressed, {minor_version,1}]),
```

Result:

`<<131,107,0,17,117,48,48,48,48,112,97,114,116,110,101,114,117,48,48,48,48>>`

but when I receive data from external service I see the payload has:

`<<0,112,97,114,116,110,101,114,0>>`

It means that one time \u0000 is converted to `<<0>>` one time to `<<131,107,0,17,117,48,48,48,48>>` as a first character in sentence and `117,48,48,48,48` and the end of the sentence.

The question is: how is it possible to convert `<<0,112,97,114,116,110,101,114,0>>` to "\u0000partner\u0000" or convert this string to `<<0,112,97,114,116,110,101,114,0>>`

Comment: I'm confused on your question. The title and the last paragraphs have very different questions (and the first and last strings are exactly the same)

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [Escape Sequences](https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#escape-sequences) section of the Erlang reference manual, Erlang doesn't support the `\uXXXX` escape format, only `\xXX` (exactly two digits) and `\x{XXXX}` (variable number of digits).

As for your question:

> It means that one time \u0000 is converted to `<<0>>` one time to `<<131,107,0,17,117,48,48,48,48>>` as a first character in sentence and `117,48,48,48,48` and the end of the sentence.

What's happening here is that `term_to_binary` creates a binary in the [External Term Format](https://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/erl_ext_dist.html).  The external term format always starts with a 131 byte, followed by a type byte.  107 is the type byte for a string, whose representation starts with a two-byte big-endian length - so the `0,17` here means that the length of the string is 17 bytes.  `117,48,48,48,48` stands for `u0000`.  `\u` is an unknown escape sequence, so it just becomes `u`, and the backslash is ignored.

So if you want to get exactly `<<0,112,97,114,116,110,101,114,0>>`, you probably want `list_to_binary`, or perhaps [`unicode:characters_to_binary`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html#characters_to_binary-1) if you might have Unicode characters in your string:

```
> Text = "\x{0000}partner\x{0000}".
[0,112,97,114,116,110,101,114,0]
> list_to_binary(Text).
<<0,112,97,114,116,110,101,114,0>>
> unicode:characters_to_binary(Text).
<<0,112,97,114,116,110,101,114,0>>
```

Alternatively, skip the string and create the binary straight away:

```
> Bin = <<"\x{0000}partner\x{0000}">>.     
<<0,112,97,114,116,110,101,114,0>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Erlang doesn't support the `\u` escape. Use `\x00` instead.

```
Text = "\x00partner\x00".
[0,112,97,114,116,110,101,114,0]
Bin = term_to_binary(Text, [compressed, {minor_version,1}]).
<<131,107,0,9,0,112,97,114,116,110,101,114,0>>
```